# .ascx drop down option value not changing when clicking the .aspx button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ascx

I have a .aspx reset button, so when the user clicks it the drop down menu value changes to the selected value (Value1). The drop down menu is implemented in .ascx (user control) and the reset button is implemented in .aspx. I already have the javascript code, .aspx code and .ascx code all implemented in a seperate file.

Below is my .aspx reset button:

```
//user clicks reset button from the .aspx page
    <input id = "resetButton" type="button" value="Reset"/>
```

Below is what my .ascx code:

```
 //drop down menu option (Value1) changes after reset button is clicked
    <select id="DropDownList">
      <option value="Value1" selected="selected">Value1</option>
      <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
      <option value="Value3">Value3</option>
    </select>
```

Below is what my javascript code looks like:

```
   //changes the drop down menu Value1 option when user clicks the resetButton
        $("#resetButton").on("click", function () {
            $('#DropDownList option').prop('selected', function() {
                return this.defaultSelected;
            });
        });
```

In my .aspx file, I have a asp placeholder tag that inherits from the javascript file. Shown below.

```
<asp:Placeholder ID= "Placeholder1" runat="server">
        <script src="../Script/Script.js"></script>
</asp:Placholder>
```

I also placed the script tag inside the .ascx file and it still doesn't work like shown below.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#resetButton").on("click", function () {
        $('#DropDownList option').prop('selected', function() {
            return this.defaultSelected;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm possibly doing wrong. I'm still trying to understand more about .aspx and .ascx.

Answer (score 0):

Your ascx id won't necessarily match the ID in your HTML. The ClientID property will tell you the HTML id via the ClientID property.

I recommend this (assuming the script is on the page).  Whatever your object's name on the form is (your ascx instance might be named DropDownList1 for example, then you would reference it this way.

```
$("#resetButton").on("click", function () {
        $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %> option').prop('selected', function() {
            return this.defaultSelected;
        });
    });
```

If the script ISN'T on the page, it's a slightly different process.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try this and see if it works. @Ctznkane525